# joomla 3 get category/articel ID and menu

Tags: joomla

I want to get some info from joomla about what menu id/article/category I am on.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$whichMenu = $active->alias;
```

Which seems to work well.

Two questions:
1) is the above code 'up to speed' - I found it on a forum.

2) How would I get the article and category ids - assuming I am on a single article layout.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to get category and article id you could echo these variables inside article layout:

```
echo $this->item->id;
echo $this->item->catid;
```

Article layout could be found at:

```
/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
```

and get overriden (if not exist) at:

```
/templates/*your_template_name/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

As for the first code (question 1) seem just fine.

**Edit:**

In order to get results inside template file you have to add the flowing code:

```
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    if($app->input->getCmd('option') == "com_content" && $app->input->getCmd('view') == "article" ) {
    $article_id = $app->input->getCmd('id');

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName('catid'));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($article_id));
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $cat_id = $db->loadResult();

    echo $article_id . " - " . $cat_id;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks. This works fine from within the default.php (or whatever) layout. However, I need to get at these numbers from within my index.php file int he template, but they don't seem to be available there.